# Regex Split : Help in Pattern needed

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I kind of stuck on this.
I have a string like

```
18=abcd1, 19=jghrt23, 20=outut
```

I have to split the given string in such a way that I get list of 18,19, 20.

The best I could do was `=(.*\w,)[^\D+=]` but obviously its not working,

Note: I could do it easily by using string.split by "," first and then by "=", but I want to use regex so that I am able to learn it.
I want to use `Regex.Split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `Split` isn't suitable for this task.

Use:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+(?==)").Cast<Match>().Select(s => s.Value);
```

Comment: It gives the opposite of what I want. the result is abcd1, jghrt23, outut and not 18, 19, 20

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do what you're asking for with one single regex, or at least you won't be able to get individual groups. You can use 2 steps:

1. Get next comma-separated element, for example with regex `^(\d+=\w*),(.*)$` For this you would need to store the remaining string somewhere to process further elements.
2. Extract the number from one element with `^(\d+)=\w+$` and store it somewhere.

PS: I'm assuming after *=* you only got alphanumeric characters.